# New Starter just spins, after couple tries works all day until morning

Tags: chevrolet, starter, s10

I replaced the starterand solenoid  on my 1992 Chevy S-10 with a new ac delco .Battery test good. my first couple starts are just a spinning sound. However after a hour of driving the starter works perfectly every time but soon as i try it next morning I get a spinning sound. Then works and great.could it be from setting on store shelves and just needs broken in? Please any help? My wife of 35 years just past and we have a diabetic son and this truck is my only transportation

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you hear any clunk at all from the starter when you try to start it, or just a spin?

Comment: It is now that you mention it’s like that . What I don’t understand it will do perfect after that

Comment: It’s kind of a clunk then just spins and today I actually had to try it twice and worked 3rd try 30 min later starters working great. I tried it  4 or 5 times and about 4 more when I got home and perfect and again right before dark. All perfect starts. Until over night same issue

Comment: It sounds like the starter isn't quite aligned correctly. Then, when a little heat gets into it, it moves just enough to work right. You'd need to see how the teeth are engaging (or not engaging). To do that, you have to engage the solenoid without engaging the starter motor. There is a copper post which sticks out of the end of the starter which has a screw through it which attaches to the back and bottom of the solenoid. Remove that connection (should be a long 5/16" headed screw) and the solenoid will kick without the motor turning. You should be able to see where it hits that way.

Comment: After that, you can shift the start to get it in a better position so it will engage like it should be.

Comment: Thanks so much. It’s just I can’t get to the front of solenoid  with starter on truck. It has the 4.3 engine and very little clearance. Should I take starter off replace solenoid. When it does that is it damaging my flywheel

Comment: You can drop the starter and disconnect as I suggested, then re-install. Then go back the other way to reconnect the motor. As long as you aren't hearing the teeth grind on each other (which would mean the starter is too far from the ring gear), you shouldn't be damaging the ring gear.

Comment: Changing starter today the 1999 suburban starter has 11 teeth and one coming off my truck has 9 teeth. Does this matter?

Comment: @RandallPenland It (*most likely*) does matter. You'll want to be sure whatever starter you install has the same gearing (i.e. the diameter, tooth count, angels, and thickness) all match the design. With the amount of force that the starter is putting on the engine, you need to be sure that everything mates and aligns well.

Comment: @RandallPenland can you post the part number for the new ac delco starter you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bad Bendix to me.

What I would do is upgrade the starter to a permanent magnet starter, they are much smaller and last longer, and draw less current.

Order a New starter at your local parts store for a 99 Chevrolet Suburban with a 350 gas engine ( I get mine at O'Reillys but might be found cheaper on Ebay or Amazon). then order new starter bolts from the Chevrolet Dealer, part number 12338064, the old bolts wont work with this new design starter.

I have upgraded many of these over the years and have not had one come back for any reason.

Comment: What is the name of the starter and is it for any size suburban? Because of the 4.3 in the small truck clearance is so tight and would the size of the starter make easier going back in? I’m open to any suggestions and thanks so much for the info

Comment: Full size suburban with 350 cu inch v-8 gas engine.

Comment: I ordered online at Oreillys a starter and they also sold starter bolts and from a 1999 suburban 1500 RWD  gas engine. I should have asked before ordering it. But will it align properly to my flywheel/flexplate? This little starter will make the right clearance so much easier and I thank you. I also order from rock auto starter bolts same numbers you listed before checking with oreillys but no worries. My truck is a 1992 Chevy S-10 2wd with a 4.3. Just making sure of the flexplate ? It’s a automatic

Comment: Never had a fitment issue on 5.7 or 4.3.

Comment: Thanks I did pickup the starter Ultima Starter
ULT R613326B from O’Riellys and two starter bolts and bolt pattern and tail housing looks to be the same at the old GM starter. I plan to replace tomorrow. Thank you so much for your input. To upgrade the starter and the size will only make my job easier. Thank you

Comment: Moab Thanks for the advice on the gear reduction starter for a 1999 suburban. Installing it on my 92 S-10 was so much easier and works great! Your advice was very helpful and Thank you all for your help. Again Thanks

Comment: Probably the last starter it will ever need, you are welcome. Give my answer an up vote if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the solenoid is going bad in your starter. The starter is an electric motor, the cylinder shaped part. The solenoid is the part on the side with the toothed wheel on it. A solenoid is an electromagnetic switch, when you turn the key, it pushes the cog on to your flexplate/flywheel on the transmission, spinning the engine. What happens is when a starter starts to die, the first thing on it to go is the solenoid. The click you hear when you go to start the car before it turns over, is the solenoid engaging.

Comment: Two things: First, OP states this is a new solenoid. Second, if the solenoid was going bad, it wouldn't engage the motor. In order for the starter motor to spin, the solenoid has to fully engage. The plunger, moved by the solenoid coil, pushes up against a pin, which pushes a copper washer against two copper contacts, which allows power to flow and the starter motor to spin. If the solenoid was going out, the starter motor wouldn't spin in the first place. The OPs issue is most likely an alignment issue of the starter itself, not allowing the starter gear to fully engage the ring gear.

Comment: Since the clearance is so tight and the two starter bolts are easy to get to. What if I loosen the bolts and maybe retighten. It was a bit hard getting the starter back up to mount the bolts and I had help putting it back in and could maybe he done something to the solenoid? It was a bit hard putting back and a smaller starter would be great

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your comments. One more question if the small wire that goes to the solenoid was pinched would this cause issue . To get to the 5/16 nut the starter has to be dropped down with just enough slack to take off and same going back in